# How to change Post Action Url for registration forms in Magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I have a Magento Site with a theme that I purchased and I want to change the post action URL for all register/signup forms on the site. After looking through both the  theme files and core files, I've come across the php function **$this->getPostActionUrl()** multiple times. Is this the function that I would have to modify? If so, which file would I need to edit in order to change the post action for all of the signup forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could manually change the `action="<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl(); ?>"` to `action="/your/desired/url"`.  Otherwise, the answer is yes.  You can change it for one form if you want and in some cases, several different forms.  I will use the customer login form for an example.

If you echo or log `get_class($this)` within your template file, you will find that the class containing your `getPostActionUrl()` is `Mage_Customer_Block_Form_Login` (it is also in a comment at the top for default templates).

So, you can copy `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Form/Login.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Customer/Block/Form/Login.php` and edit the `public function getPostActionUrl()` on line 49 to return the value you want.

**Note:**  this is the "quick and dirty" way of doing it.  The right way is to [Extend/Override the class](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/133191/33071)